# Added items don't appear in typeahead

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

```
// JS script
var company = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'json/receiver-company.json'
});

$('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'company',
    display: 'name',
    source: company,
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
            'No results found.',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: function(data){
            return '<p><strong>' + data.name + '</strong></p>';
        }
    }
});

// json/receiver-company.json
[
    {"company_id":"1","name":"Company One"},
    {"company_id":"2","name":"Company Two"},
    {"company_id":"3","name":"Company Three"},
    {"company_id":"4","name":"Company Four"}
]
```

I'm using using  [Twitter's typeahead prefetch](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch) to populate a field. It was working, but when I added a new item to the JSON file, it did not appear in the typeahead list. I tried clearing my cache and restarting the browser. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already solved my own problem. . .

just add `cache = false` to prefetch like this.

```
 prefetch: {
      url: 'json/receiver-company.json',
      cache: false
 }
```

this is where i found it [bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)